# displaying decimal values from database in textbox

Tags: c#, ms-access, textbox

i just want to ask how to set the textbox so it will display decimal numbers. Couse now if i read a decimal number from my access database like 0,2 it displays only 0
Tnx for the help!

Comment: Are the numbers (for example 0,2) stored as strings or actual numeric types in your Access database?

Comment: How are you populating the textbox?  Its more likely that you've got a problem in your data access or data binding where you're accidentally retrieving/casting the value as an integer instead of a decimal.  By default, the textbox shouldn't be altering the value (unless of course the problem is that you've got it set to a max length of 1 in which case its truncating)

Comment: @Adam.... they are stored as double(at first they were stored as an integer so i changed to double and the numbers were stored in the correct form in the database)

Answer (score 0):

Check the format options on the text box to make sure it is set to fixed or standard and the number of decimal places is more than 0!

EDIT:

Here is a more verbose answer

- Open the form in design mode
- Make sure the properties window is displayed, if it is not then right click on the control and click on properties
- Go to the “Format” tab, under that tab is a field called “format” and another called “decimal places”
- Alter these so they show “General Number” and “Auto”

That should do the trick

Comment: Kevin - simon is not working in access but coding in C# so your verbose answer won't help much...

Comment: This is one of the problems with the MS-ACCESS tag -- it covers too much. In this case, Access is not involved at all, only the Jet/ACE database engine. I started answering this yesterday before I realized that it wasn't an Access question at all.

Comment: @david Very good point about the tags and how most people think jet=access.

Comment: I think it's good for your answer to be here, since someone working in Access could get to this question seeking the very explanation you've given, even though it's not applicable to the specific question.